# Splitting Dataframe by group Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file full of rating data from a preference experiment. The file is fairly basic and has 5 rows, of which i need 4 (participant, image, fluency, rating and version)

I have created a Dataframe to isolate the columns that I need and I have split the frame by fluency (1 and 4) so I can get a group mean rating for each fluency.

I cant work out how to split the file per participant (each person has 2 preference ratings per fluency) to get individual ratings.

Below is my code for reference.

I'm fairly new at coding so it might not be the most efficient way.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create dataframe from csv file and import only the colums you want
df = pd.read_csv('Pre-experiment.csv', usecols=[0,2,3,4])



pre_fluent = df[df['Fluency']== 1]
pre_disfluent = df[df['Fluency']==4]
pre_version1 = df[df['Version']==1]
pre_version2 = df[df['Version']==2]

print (pre_fluent)
print (pre_disfluent)
pre_mean_fluent = np.mean(pre_fluent)
pre_mean_disfluent = np.mean(pre_disfluent)
print (pre_mean_fluent)
print (pre_mean_disfluent)

df1 = pd.read_csv('Post-experiment.csv', usecols=[0,2,3,4])
#print (df)


post_fluent = df1[df['Fluency']== 1]
post_disfluent = df1[df['Fluency']==4]
post_version1 = df1[df['Version']==1]
post_version2 = df1[df['Version']==2]

print ("Dataframe sortted by fluency: {}".format(post_fluent))
print (post_disfluent)

post_mean_fluent = np.mean(post_fluent)
post_mean_disfluent = np.mean(post_disfluent)
print ("Post_Fluent Mean:   {}".format(post_mean_fluent))
print ("Post_Disfluent Mean: {}".format(post_mean_disfluent))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the question?

Comment: Could you post an example of what your data looks like, and what you want the end output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible answer

It is not entirely clear what you are looking for, but if you need to group your dataframe by `Participant`, try setting that as the index using [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.set_index('Participant', inplace=True)
```

Let's say you have participants `A` and `B`. You can get all of the `Fluency` values for participant `A` with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`df.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (for referencing by location rather than name):

```
fluency_A = df.loc['A']['Fluency']  # or df.loc['A', 'Fluency']
```

This might depend a bit on how your actual data is formatted, but hopefully it gets you close to what you are looking for.

## A working example

```
# Make up some data that we can read into our dataframe.
data = io.StringIO("""Participant,Fluency,Other
A,1,5
A,2,5
B,3,6
B,4,6""")
# Read the data, set the index, and get Fluency for "A".
df = pd.read_csv(data)
df.set_index('Participant', inplace=True)
df.loc['A']['Fluency']
# Participant
# A    1
# A    2
# Name: Fluency, dtype: int64
```

**Edit:** as mentioned in a comment, you can use `df.loc['A', 'Fluency']` as well, but I ran in to some issues with this in my own work when I have a complicated multi-index. The format used here: `df.loc[index_specification][column_specification]` seems to work more consistently for me.

Comment: IMO `df.loc['A', 'Fluency']` is more idiomatic compared to `df.loc['A']['Fluency']`

Comment: Thank you, This really helped.

Comment: @BryonyMcKean glad I could help. When you get a few more reputation points, please mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you. That way people coming across your question in the future will know what worked.